# .focus() Not Focusing On New Element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function for renaming certain divs. The way I'm trying to get it to work is like this:

- User right clicks div
- User clicks 'Rename' on context menu
- Div gets an input element and is automatically focused
- The input gets submitted after pressing enter or clicking the screen

I have most of the steps done but the input element is not being focused after I click 'rename'. Here's the code:

```
function Rename( ){
    ClickedFile.innerHTML = "<input class='Rename' type='text' value='" + ClickedFile.innerHTML + "'>";
    ClickedFile.childNodes[0].focus();
}
```

The ClickedFile is the node that was right clicked. Changing The innerHTML works fine but the .focus() does not and I'm not sure why. I don't get any errors on the console, either.

I've also tried using:

```
ClickedFile.childNodes[0].select();
ClickedFile.childNodes[1].focus();
ClickedFile.focus();
```

None of them have worked.

Edit:

- I know using JQuery might help, but I'm more interested in finding out why this isn't working.
- I fixed the problem. It has something to do with event handlers. My answer is posted below.

Comment: @tadman jQuery?? What the heck is this for? It is like saying *Why you're not using CodeIgniter in the first place. It makes very hard to get wrong.*

Comment: What you have seems to work fine for me [here](http://jsbin.com/epeyoy/1/).

Comment: I'm not using it so that I get a better understanding of pure javascript. I'd really rather not debate here whether or not I should be using jQuery anyway

Comment: @tadman Read my last comment

Comment: Since this is a JavaScript question, policy seems to be: [Don't answer it telling the asker to use jQuery.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45176/152515) Just answer with JavaScript, unless jQuery or other frameworks are explicitly requested, or named as being used.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the element as part of DOM

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.className = "Rename";
input.type = "text";

document.getElementById("somenode").appendChild(input);
input.focus(); // should work now
```

see [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UXZgA/)

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's still not working, I might post more code if I can't get that to work

Comment: @TaylorFlores check the fiddle in my updated answer. works for me.

Comment: yeah, it works but I'm having problems using it on my page. I'll post a fiddle shortly

Comment: @TaylorFlores so... where's the fiddle?

Comment: I'm working on it now. Sorry, I had to pick my brother up from school

Comment: I posted a fiddle and the link to the actual page. The actual page demonstrates the problem. But, it has major security holes right now, so I'm gonna remove it as soon as it is practical.

Comment: Can confirm after the on-page load this can able to focus.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that since you're immediately invoking the select and focus methods. The browser didn't have a chance yet to insert the element so it's not part of the DOM.

A quick and dirty solution is to use the `setTimeout`-function with a value of 0 milliseconds:

```
function Rename( ){
    ClickedFile.innerHTML = "<input class='Rename' type='text' value='" + ClickedFile.innerHTML + "'>";
    setTimeout(function(){ClickedFile.childNodes[0].focus();}, 0);
}
```

This causes the browser to do everything it has to do, and then run the function you passed into the `setTimeout`

The following fiddle shows your example in a working state: http://jsfiddle.net/Kennethtruyers/fX8h6/

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't mention that I tried that too from what I saw in a similar question. Didn't quite help

Comment: What's the value of innerHTML before you do this? Are you sure that it's not breaking your textnox?

Comment: the innerHTML before is just a filename ( ie <div>testFile.c</div>

Comment: I think your best shot would be to create a jsfiddle, so we can try some things out

Comment: I just tried some things out and your original code seems to work OK in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: You save my time

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by changing the function that renames the div to be triggered on 'mouseup' instead of 'mousedown'.

I think the reason this was causing a problem is because the Rename() function was being triggered on mousedown, causing the focus to be set during 'mousedown', but the contextmenu wasn't being hidden until 'mouseup'.

I can't confirm that's the reason but I do know that the code works after 'mousedown' was changed to 'mouseup' for the trigger of Rename().

Comment: I feel a little bit bad that the reason no one could answer the question is because I did not post the entire code. Sorry about that!